# Write multiple variables in a file to can read them later

Tags: bash, file, variables, command, sh

It's there a simple way to write multiple variables into a file and later to read them?

For example to write the next variables into a file:

```
test=1
b=3
a=earth

echo "test=1" > variables.prop
echo "b=3" >> variables.prop
echo "a=earth" >> variables.prop
```

And somehow to return the value of specified variable and use it.
Like

```
*command to import the variable "test" from the text file*
echo $test

*command to import the variable "b" from the text file*
echo $b
```

and the expected output for "test" should be "1" and for "b" to be "3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `variables.prop` exactly as you're doing, then use the `.` command (AKA `source`) to read it in.

```
. variables.prop

echo "$test"
echo "$b"
```